# Grub rescue error after deleting Ubuntu from dual boot with windows 10

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, manjaro

I deleted Ubuntu from windows 10 dual boot setup as I wanted to install manjaro Linux in this setup.So I deleted the partitions and removed the grub using diskpart method from windows command prompt.
Now my windows is working fine but when I tried installing manjaro from bootable pendrive grub rescue appeared with error: **unknown filesystem**.
I am not sure how to proceed forward.I checked other answers telling me to setprefix but this doesn't work for me. 
Commands I tried-

**set prefix=(hd0,2)boot/grub**

**Set root=(hd0,2)**

**Insmod normal**

This gives me **error:no such partition**.So I tried all partitions.Still doesn't work.

Also I don't understand why installing manjaro gives me Ubuntu grub rescue error.

[disk scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1z0L.png)
This is disk scheme

[boot menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q820o.jpg)

[boot rescue error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NS7Es.jpg)

Update-I installed Mint 18.2 to check if the error will appear in its installation but it installed fine.After that when I retried to install Manjaro, same grub rescue screen appeared.

[Dual boot Installed Mint OS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMDKA.jpg)

[Grub dispayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvAlR.jpg)

[Grub rescue screen when trying to install manjaro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opdA7.jpg)

Comment: So at this point, you have a drive with Win 10 partitions and a chunk of unallocated space?  A simple thing to try would be to use diskpart to create empty partitions for Manjaro before you try to install it.

Comment: I have created partitions for manjaro but when I try to install it using bootable pendrive grub rescue screen appears.

Comment: 1. What did you use to make the pendrive bootable?  2. Try using diskpart to format those Manjaro partitions ext4 before trying to install Manjaro.  3. If #2 doesn't work.  Create a pendrive for something like Mint, which is extremely forgiving and very installable.  Install that in the space you are planning for Manjaro.  If that doesn't work, there's something else going on.  But if it does work, then install Manjaro to replace it.

Comment: I used Rufus to make the pendrive bootable.Also if I install mint and then replace it with manjaro,won't I have to delete grub again to replace it with manjaro?If yes,then I fear I may reach same error unless I understand what went wrong in first place.

Comment: If Mint installs, don't do any kind of prep with diskpart.  When you install Manjaro, it will see Mint there and ask you what you want to do.  You will have choices like let Manjaro do whatever it wants with the space, overwriting whatever Mint did; or install Manjaro in addition to Mint; or let you pick where and how to install Manjaro; etc.  Pick the option where you define things.  Then pick the same partition(s) for Manjaro.  If you picked reasonable sizes for Mint, you won't need to recreate the partitions, themselves, for Manjaro; (cont'd)

Comment: if you want to tweak the partition sizes at that time, do it with the Manjaro installer; Manjaro is fussy, but it has no issues with its own work).  You do that by telling Manjaro to reformat those partitions, and define the mount point for each one (if just 1, then `/`, if separate ones for root and Home, specify that).  BTW if you have the drive space, create a swap partition equal to 1 to 2 times your RAM, which will give any Linux distro some breathing room.  (cont'd)

Comment: You can do it when you install Mint, and Manjaro will see it and use it without your having to do anything.  Otherwise, you can carve it out with the Manjaro installer.  You just create a partition that size and in the window where you tell it the usage/filesystem, pick "swap".  It doesn't even get formatted and it doesn't matter if something was previously there; it's just a chunk of scratch space the system will write to.  For the Manjaro partitions, the formatting will use the same partitions but wipe any vestiges of Mint content.  (cont'd)

Comment: The mount points tell Manjaro to make those partitions its own.  You'll also specify where to install GRUB, which will replace what Mint put there.  If it's just one physical drive, Grub will likely be on that device, itself, rather than in a partition (like `sda` rather than `sda1`).

Comment: @fixer1234 So i followed your advice and installed Mint.But grub rescue still appears when trying to intall manjaro.Please check my update on question.

Comment: You're jinxed, that's the only possible explanation.  :-)  I'm not quite following exactly what's happening.  I typically install Linux from a DVD rather than a flash drive because it's simpler.  I've never encountered the need to use any terminal commands for the process.  I haven't got a clue where you're running into the need for setprefix, or where "unknown filesystem" could appear from.  If Mint installed without a problem, you don't have hardware issues.  I just looked at your disk scheme image, and that's not what things should look like after Mint has been installed.  (cont'd)

Comment: It shows a whole collection of Windows partitions and a chunk of unallocated space.  Where did Mint and the Linux partitions go?  It looks like you're injecting procedures before installing Manjaro that undo all of your Mint preparation.  But even from that point, the Manjaro installer could create what it needs in the unallocated space.  Manjaro doesn't like how Ubuntu (Mint) sets up GRUB, but it replaces Mint's GRUB when it installs.  The only thing I can think of is that after installing Mint, you deleted Mint's partition, (cont'd)

Comment: perhaps leaving some stub of the boot system that's confusing something in the process you use next.  The problems you're running into may be because you're interfering in what should be a very simple, automated process, designed so that total noobs in Linux can do it by just clicking the install button.  Stop doing things.  :-)  If you can get back to having Mint installed, everything will be ready for Manjaro.  Just start the Manjaro live session and tell it to install.  Then follow the earlier advice on what settings to use during that process.

Comment: @fixer1234 Actually the disk scheme is before installing mint.So new scheme is actually alright and has no unallocated space (I will upload a pic later).But this jinx has raised a question about how grub actually works and why mint will install but manjaro will ask to repair grub.

Comment: Each operating system has a boot loader to start it up.  When you install a Linux distro, it installs (replaces) any existing GRUB.  GRUB functions as a menu to select the boot loader you want.  Its installation process includes searching all accessible drives/partitions to find all of the boot loaders that are there for other OSes.  It then incorporates those into its menu so one GRUB instance can launch anything on the computer.  An OS's bootloader can be in several chunks.  The first is in a designated standard location, and that points to the next chunk.  (cont'd)

Comment: If you install Mint, say, not all of it's boot loader is inside the Mint partition.  If you delete the Mint partition, that leaves a stub of Mint's boot loader somewhere else.  When you Install Manjaro, and its GRUB installer goes looking for other OSes to incorporate, it finds the stub but not what that stub points to, and recognizes that something is wrong with that picture.  It can be repaired by doing some investigation and cleanup that's beyond the capabilities of what the OS installer is designed to do.  (cont'd)

Comment: If Mint was left in place, Manjaro's installer would find all of the pieces, recognize that you're replacing Mint so it wouldn't see a problem.

Comment: The problem is solved now.I made  the bootable pendrive in DD mode instead of iso mode,which I guess works for most other distros but not for Manjaro.Now it is working fine.Thankyou for your help.I really appreciate it. @fixer1234

Comment: Kudos for solving this.  Consider posting an answer to explain what you discovered and how you solved it.  That will help anyone else who runs into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved now.I had to write the bootable pendrive in DD image in rufus.Now it is working fine.Thank you